# Help factoring third order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble factoring $y'''-y''+y'+3y=0$
I put it into derivative form $D^3-D^2+D+3=0$, and tried to factor by guessing one root was $D-1 $or $D+1$. However either way gives me a remainder of 2. Anyone mind pointing out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do the usual thing ... Assume there is a solution of the form $y=Ae^{\lambda x} ... try and factorise the cubic ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/h7qas0ckj9

Comment: The real root of the characteristic polynomial is pretty complicated-looking, are you quite certain that you have the problem written correctly?

Comment: Yes I miswrote it, apologies. I corrected a minus sign in front of y', I think this will change the result of my work

Comment: andrea you should correct the D equation too

Comment: For the suggested correction, $D=-1$ is indeed a root, for what it's worth.

Comment: it seems to me that $D=-1$ works $P(D)=(D+1)(D^2-2D+3)$